# Passing and array argument to C from Python using SWIG

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, swig

I am using SWIG + Python + C for the first time, and I am having trouble passing an array from Python to C.

Here is a function signature in C.

```
my_setup(char * my_string, int my_count, int my_types[], double my_rate, int my_mode);
```

I would like to call this C function from Python as follows

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
my_setup("My string", 6, my_array, 50, 0)
```

but I do not know how to construct the array `my_array`. The error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_script.py", line 9, in <module>
    r = my_library.my_setup("My string", 6, my_types, 50, 0)
TypeError: in method 'my_setup', argument 3 of type 'int []'
```

I have tried unsuccessfully to use the [SWIG interface file for numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html) and [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

I hope someone can help me pass an array as the third argument of the function `my_setup`.

Also, this is my first stack overflow post!

Answer (score 1):

Parse the Python list inside `my_setup()` instead of trying to translate it in your SWIG `.i` file.  Change

```
my_setup(char * my_string, int my_count, int my_types[], double my_rate, int my_mode);
```

to

```
my_setup(char * my_string, int my_count, PyObject *int_list, double my_rate, int my_mode);
```

and in my_setup

```
    int *array = NULL;
    if ( PyList_Check( int_list ) )
    {
        int nInts = PyList_Size( int_list );
        array = malloc( nInts * sizeof( *array ) );
        for ( int ii = 0; ii < nInts; ii++ )
        {
            PyObject *oo = PyList_GetItem( int_list, ii );
            if ( PyInt_Check( oo ) )
            {
                array[ ii ] = ( int ) PyInt_AsLong( oo );
            }
        }
    }
```

You'll have to add error checking.  And from C, always return a `PyObject *` back to Python when you're using SWIG.  That way, you can use `PyErr_SetString()` and return NULL to toss an exception.